# How can I prevent pandas read_html from flattening cell contents?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using python and pandas to import HTML tables. Some table cells contain multiple items, in the form of HTML lists:

```html
<td>
  <ul>
     <li>One</li>
     <li>Two</li>
     <li>Three</li>
</td>
```

In the dataframe, this cell contains the string `OneTwoThree`. I've tried passing this column through a converter, but the converter function receives the already concatenated cell contents.

Is there any way to control how this type of structured cell data is imported? For example, I was expecting my converter would receive the raw `<ul>`, then I could return a comma separated list `One, Two, Three`.

Comment: Can you provide a fully reproducible example?

Comment: This is not directly possible with `pandas.read_html` you have to parse the data yourself (see duplicates)